# How to remove focus in stenciljs E2E testing

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, e2e-testing, stenciljs

In end-to-end testing using newE2EPage from stenciljs you can invoke focus() on an element to set focus on the element:

```
   const page = await newE2EPage({html: `<my-component></my-component>`});
   const el = await page.find('my-component');
   await el.focus();
```

How do you remove focus from the element?

P.S. I've tried setting focus on a second element but this does not seem to work.

P.P.S. page.find() is how you do querySelector on an E2EPage from Stencil newE2EPage.  Documentation is at: https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing#find-an-element-in-the-shadow-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `page.find()` method?

Try to move the focus by clicking another element.

```
await page.click(selector)
```

Comment: page.find() method is what is provided by newE2EPage as a standin for querySelector.  Refer here: https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing#find-an-element-in-the-shadow-dom

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tested all three methods and of the three await page.click(selector) works.  The other two methods page.focus and page.$eval do not work.  page.focus simply does not do the job and page.$eval will not compile.  If you can change the answer to just page.click(selector) I will mark it as correct.  It might be worth mentioning that the other two methods do not work.

Comment: sure, just changed the answer.